Python: Subtract one 2D line from another
The problem
I need to calculate the difference between the two lines (ie. subtract one from the other), which should result in an output line.
The input lines - and output line - may include vertical sections. ie. the X values for the lines may not be monotonically increasing (although they won't go back on themselves).
This is probably easiest to demonstrate with an example:
Input:
# lines represented as arrays of (X,Y) coordinates
line1 = [ (0,2), (4,2), (5,10), (15,10), (16,0), (20,0) ]
line2 = [ (0,2), (5,2), (10,5), (15,5), (15,0), (20,0) ]

This is represented by the following chart (made in Excel):

Output:
Ideally I'm looking for a library which can take line1 & line2 as input, and output the vertices representing the difference between the lines (AKA line1 minus line2). So for this example:
[ (0,0), (4,0), (5,8), (10,5), (15,5), (15,10), (16,0), (20,0) ]

Again, probably easier to visualise with a chart - although note, I am looking for a library which outputs the result as a Python object - ideally vertices or similar - not a library which just draws a chart:

Notes about the input & output data:

The lines between two points are straight, not curves
line1 & line2 do not contain all the same X values
X points on a line will never go backwards, but we can have multiple points on a line with the same X value which are next to each other - representing a vertical line. Eg. line2 contains duplicate points at X=15, because there is a vertical line from (X=15,Y=5) to (X=15,Y=0).
Similarly, the output data may need to represent vertical lines.

Potential solutions I've looked into
I am relatively new to the Python ecosystem, and am not a math / geometry / graph expert. I have tried to research various Python libraries, but the documentation for these is often heavy on math terminology, so it's entirely possible I am missing something obvious.
Pandas Series - it looks like this would work perfectly if I had monotonically increasing X values... But I don't...
SymPy Geometry - it may be possible to subtract 2d lines / polygons with SymPy in the way I want, but I haven't been able to locate anything obvious in the documentation...
SciPy - this StackOverflow answer uses scipy.interpolate.interp1d to do almost what I want to do...
As far as I can see, you can feed interp1d a series of points including duplicate X values and it will represent the shape of the line correctly:
>>> x_values = [0,1,1]
>>> y_values = [0,0,10]
>>> curve = sc.interpolate.interp1d(x_values, y_values)
>>> curve(0)
array(0.)
>>> curve(1)
array(10.)
>>> curve(0.9999)
array(0.)

There is a vertical line at X=1, so getting the the Y value at X<1 gives 0, while X=1 gives 10.
However, if I were to do something like the above linked Stack Overflow answer:
# This would lose the duplicates representing the vertical line
all_x_values = sorted(set(line1_x_values + line2_x_values))

# Even if we had maintained all the X values, in our original example we would
# have two X=15 values here... The first call to line1(15) would need to return
# Y = 5, the second call to line1(15) would need to return Y = 0...
new_line_y_values = [line1(x) - line2(x) for x in all_x_values]

# And if we got this far with everything working, how do we extract the vertices
# from the new line - including multiple points at the same X-value for any vertical
# lines?
new_line = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(all_x_values, new_line_y_values)


Add points to each polyline (by interpolation if necessary) so that: (a) they have the same x values; (b) if an x value is repeated in one then it is repeated in the other. Then just do a straight subtraction of y coordinates.

Thanks @lastchance, this is what I'd concluded as well if I have to hand-roll something - but I assumed with the ecosystem of Python libraries out there for maths / graphing / scientific calculations, this would be a solved problem wrapped up in a well-tested library. Maybe not though?

AFAIK, there is no pre-built functions in libraries for this, but you can do pure Python :
line3 = [
    (ix, abs(t1[1]-t2[1]))
    for ix in set(x for x,y in [*line1, *line2])
    for t1 in [(x,y) for x,y in line1 if x==ix] or [(ix, 0)]
    for t2 in [(x,y) for x,y in line2 if x==ix] or [(0, t1[1])]
]

Output :
line3 # [(0, 0), (4, 0), (5, 8), (10, 5), (15, 5), (15, 10), (16, 0), (20, 0)]



Thanks @Timeless! It's a very clean solution which works for the example!
I think there's some assumptions which can't be made in general though. For example, for t1 in [(x,y) for x,y in line1 if x==ix] or [(ix, 0)]. Defaulting to 0 when there's not a point with the same X does work for this example. The point where it matters is X=10, where we want 10 - 5. Luckily in this example the code ends up with the correct answer of 5, because it does Y1=0 minus Y2=5, and takes the absolute difference.
In general it needs to interpolate Y at the given X if there isn't an exact matching point.

There's also the fun edge case where both lines have vertical sections at the same time. This is most simply demonstrated by subtracting a line from itself - we should end up with a flat line (all zeroes). Eg. line = [ (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,1) ]. If I do line - line using the algorithm above, the output has four points at X=1 - two of them with Y=0 and two of them with Y=1 - [(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)].
Appreciate the useful code and seems as if this may not be a problem others have solved with a library, so may have to hand-roll myself.
